# Getting NoMethodError when raking db for devise generate user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After I install rails and generate devise User and run rake:db migrate. Here's what I get

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for #     <ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x000000078edc88>
```

I also did manual configuration in my config/enviroments/development.rb file

Comment: do you have Rails 4.2? There is known issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3158

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring it out. Thank you